# How to melt an object into fluid and then morph into another object?

Tags: animation, transforms, fluid-simulation

I am a beginner in Blender. I really want to accomplish a short 3D animation, I have built the models but I don't know how to deal with the animation. I watched many tutorials about fluid simulation but I still don't know how to finish my animation.

These are my models:
[image]

And this is a sketch of how I want the animation:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I was trying to use fluid with Domain and obstacle, but I couldn't achieve that animation effect.

I am confuse about what Blender tools I can use for this.

Here is my blender file:

[image]

Best wishes to all!

Comment: I don't think you can get a satisfying result with the built in simulator. You better try a Mantaflow Branch.

Comment: Thank you very much！I don't know about Mantaflow Branch before, and I would go serch for the tutorial , thanks for commentting!

Comment: This is morphing and in Blender it's done with **shape keys** which have their own editor.

Comment: Also look at the Lattice Modifier. You can construct a Lattice that affects everything passing through it. Best example is a car going through a keyhole, but can do a lot more.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would try that!

Comment: By the way, does anyone could help me to make it in blender files directly? I would very appreciate, and if necessary, I would do my best to reward it.